# Select rows before date via MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following query:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(o.date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date_created, op.*
FROM order_product op
WHERE o.date_created > '2009-01-01';
```

This should run all orders that are AFTER 1st Jan 2009, but when I run if it rows that are BOTH before and after 2009??

What is the mistake I made?

Comment: @VMai If it's returning both before and after now, why would inverting the test fix that?

Comment: @VMai he doesn't want data before the specified date

Comment: The issue is that you are expecting o.date_created to be in YYYY-MM-DD format, when in reality it is still a timestamp value.

Comment: I'm expecting this isn't the whole query, as there are mismatched columns and table aliases.

Comment: I guess your `FROM` part should be like this `FROM order_product as o, op`

Comment: @AlexGreg I looked at the title of the question: **Select rows before date via MySQL**

Comment: @VMai But you didn't actually read the question?

Comment: @VMai guess he specified his problem in the title :-)

Comment: at all: I didn't exactly understood the question, so I took to the title. But Dan is right, it's a problem of data type what I have missed :-(

Comment: @BrianDriscoll that isn't the issue, it should work fine if date_created is indeed a TIMESTAMP not an INT.

Comment: @VMai that isn't the issue, it should work fine if date_created is indeed a TIMESTAMP not an INT.

Comment: @Arth I fear - even if OP said it was timestamp - that he's using INT and storing an unix timestamp. Otherwise Dans solution wouldn't work. I'm trying to read properly now and do not want to come to premature decisions :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to be that o.date_created is unix time, and not in the format you want for the query.

Try

```
WHERE o.date_created > unix_timestamp('2009-01-01');
```

Comment: Just throwing this on here: generally you want to avoid calling functions in your where clauses because they are evaluated for every row in the potential result set.

Comment: Why is this upvoted? MySQL can handle that conversion.. unless they've stored that unix_timestamp an int (heaven forbid).

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Nope, this'll be done just once. It's fine if it's not a function on a column/index column, this is a constant.

Comment: @Arth Yeah I know since it's a constant it'll only be done once, but sometimes inexperienced devs will do something like `WHERE fn(some_column)`, so I was just trying to warn in advance.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Fair enough, but you should make your warnings more specific.. I can imagine people freaking out about functions and doing manual timestamp conversions otherwise! :)

Comment: @Arth, depending on the use of the column `o.date_created` and how else the contents of the row can be changed after creation.  From what I know, a timestamp field will be updated any and every time a row is updated.  This may not be the desired affect.

Comment: @Dan: only if you say so: *To specify automatic properties, use the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses in column definitions.*, see [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: @Dan maybe, but then calling it date_created is mad, and that really doesn't have much to do with your answer.

Comment: @Zabs What datatype are you using for date_created?

Comment: @Arth it is a timestamp

Comment: @Zabs are you ABSOLUTELY sure it's not a timestamp in an INT column.. your original query will work if it is a TIMESTAMP type.

Comment: @Arth i'll check that out shortly, thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this and thinks that the accepted answer is the only way to get this to work.

The original comparison will work perfectly well:

```
 WHERE date_created > '2009-01-01'
```

Provided that `date_created` is of type `TIMESTAMP` and not an `INT` pretending to be a timestamp.

MySQL is clever enough to be able to convert '2009-01-01' to a `TIMESTAMP` for the comparison. (As a disclaimer, this may break if the default date format is tampered with, but I'm not convinced).

As a side note, I would also change `from_unixtime(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d')` to `DATE(date_created)` as it appears to return `NULL` otherwise.

Comment: Did you test the `from_unixtime(o.date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date_created` part too? If it's a TIMESTAMP, OP should use `DATE_FORMAT(o.date_created, '%Y-%m-%d')` instead.

Comment: @VMai That bit is ok I guess looking at the docs, DATE_FORMAT() would involve an extra conversion.

Comment: @VMai you are correct, I have updated the answer to just the relevant section on the comparison.

Comment: @Arth What about showing the complete query with DATE_FORMAT. It's a minor issue, you could mention it. I think it would be better. Otherwise our visitor may stumble upon the FROM_UNIXTIME part.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to check your database's locale configuration, as the default date format might vary from one installation to another (eg: yyyy-mm-dd, mm-dd-yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy).

It could be safer to explicitly define the date format, something like:

WHERE to_char(o.date_created,'yyyy-mm-dd') > '2009-01-01'

or

WHERE FORMAT(o.date_created,'YYYY-MM-DD') > '2009-01-01'

Please use the corresponding date format function available on your database type (mysql).

Comment: This is logically the same as Dan's answer, except it's worse because you have rendered any index on `create_date` unusable.